# The command "cmake -S . -B builde -G "Unix Makefiles" " no longer seems to work on my windows machine (not able to compile a simple test program)

Tags: c++, windows, shell, cmake

I just discovered that the following command cmake -S . -B build -G "Unix Makefiles" doesn't seem to work anymore on my windows machine.

I use it to build a ParticleSystem project I made in c++ using CMake and SDL2.
Here is the run.sh file :

```
#!/bin/bash

#Create a build directory and navigate into it
rm -rf build
mkdir build

build_type=Debug 

#Generate the Makefile using CMake
cmake -S . -B build/$build_type -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$build_type
cmake --build build/$build_type --target ParticleSystem


#Check if the compilation was successful
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Compilation successful. Running the ParticleSystem..."
    #Execute the ParticleSystem binary
    ./build/*/ParticleSystem
else
    echo "Compilation failed. Please check the error messages."
fi
```

Git bash's terminal returns me the following output :

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - br
oken
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompile
r.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "D:/Program Files (x86)/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: 'C:/Users/Utilisateur/Desktop/ParticleSystem/build/Debug/CMakeFi
les/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ap672m'

    Run Build Command(s): "D:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E env VERBOSE=
1 "D:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe" -f Makefile cmTC_003d3/fast
    D:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_003d3.dir/b
uild.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_003d3.dir/build
    /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `D:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe  -f C
MakeFiles/cmTC_003d3.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_003d3.dir/build'
    make.exe: *** [cmTC_003d3/fast] Erreur 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make.exe: Makefile: No such file or directory
make.exe: *** Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « Makefile ». Arrêt.
Compilation failed. Please check the error messages.
```

A few days ago, this file worked perfectly. The problem seems to come from the "Unix Makefiles" generator because when I use another generator like "Ninja" or "MinGW", it works. I made the choice of this generator because it is compatible between windows and linux, so my program was cross-platform.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(ParticleSystem)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Werror -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Debug")
    set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Debug)
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
else()
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Release")
    set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Release)
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

set(SDL2_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SDL2/cmake)

set(SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/particle.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/particles.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/application.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/vector2.cpp
)
set(HEADERS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/particle.h
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/particles.h
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/application.h
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/vector2.h
)

# Add the appropriate flags for Windows
if(WIN32)
    # Check if the system is 32-bit or 64-bit
    if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
        set(SDL2_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SDL2/lib/x64)
    else()
        set(SDL2_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SDL2/lib/x86)
    endif()

    # Add the SDL2.dll file to the binary directory for Windows
    file(COPY ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/SDL2.dll DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

    find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
    if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
        set(SDL2_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SDL2/lib/x64)
    else()
        set(SDL2_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SDL2/lib/x86)
    endif()

    set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SDL2/include)

    include_directories(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
    link_directories(SDL2_LIB_DIR)

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2main SDL2)

endif()
```

I must specify that I had to reinstall git on my machine because with git bash, the git clone --recursive command didn't seem to work. Now the command works, but I don't know if it was this reinstallation that caused the problem.

I tried to uninstall and the reinstall mingw64, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: `D:/Program Files (x86)` and `/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token \`('` - the root point of the issue is here.

Comment: Always make backups.  That will enable you to answer "What did I do differently from when it last worked."  Also, automate the build process as much as possible.

Comment: I don't understand this issue :/

Comment: "The problem seems to come from the "Unix Makefiles" generator" - Yes, that generator is for pure Linux environment. It is NOT MinGW, and it is never suited for MinGW compiler. "I made the choice of this generator because it is compatible between windows and linux, so my program was cross-platform." - This is wrong. You cannot compile the program once and run it under Windows and Linux. You need to have 2 different builds for that (with different generator/compiler).

Comment: Your bash shell should not be using windows paths.

Comment: A side note on uninstalling/reinstalling the toolchain: It almost never works, so unless an expert (and you one day might be that expert) tells you that your toolchain is broken you're probably wasting your time by reinstalling the tools.

Comment: for the record, `Ninja` also exits on linux, and will be a lot faster than `Unix Makefiles` once your program is bigger than two files, so you should be using it instead, the fact that it solves your build problem is extra cherry on the cake.

Comment: Rehashing comments above, MinGW stands for Minimalist Gnu for Windows. In many cases, this being one of them, it's too minimalist to mock up a UNIX system. That said, I've had great luck with [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) getting close enough to work. If you need gcc on Windows and you aren't using MSYS2, at this time, you're handicapping yourself.

Comment: Nice thanks for all your answers. I clearly made a lot of mistakes ! x) 
I'm not a professional sry. For Unix Makefiles I think I used WSL without paying attention, so I thought it was cross-platform, but I swear that the project worked on windows with this generator ! And okay I think I will use Ninja Generator now.

Answer (score 0):

Makefile do not support well space in path...